# como descargo un zip o file con nodejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

me exporta los datos y lo comprime en un ZIP pero deseo que me descargue el archivo y lo indique en el browser que se ha descargado algo asi como mega o mediafir;
hasta ahora lo que me hace es guardarlo pero sin avisarle al usuario que se descargo y es lo que quiero realizar.

Alguna recomendación para poder descargar el archivo file o el zip como si fuera mega o de cualquier server, quisiera poder de verdad como realizar esta parte porque no se como hacerla e estado investigando en la documentacion pero nada al respecto :(

```
   router.post('/migrate', async (req, res) => {

  let eventos = req.body.evento, scenes = [];
  eventos.forEach(async evento => {
    //crear carpeta del evneto a exportar
    try {
     fs.mkdir(join(global.__rootdir, `public/${evento}`),
        (e) => {
          if (!e || (e && e.code === 'EEXIST')) {

          } else {
           
            console.log(e)
          }
        }
      );
      console.log(`carpeta ${evento} creada exitosamente`)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error al crear la carpeta ${evento} \n${e}`)
    }

    let dataEvento = await Event.findOne({ id: evento }) //buscamos los datos en la base de dato

    // creando el archivo event.json 
    try {
      fs.writeFile(join(global.__rootdir, `public/${evento}/${evento}.json`), JSON.stringify(dataEvento),
        (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
        }
      );
      
      console.log('El archivo del evento ha sido creado')

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error al crear el archivo event.json \n${e}`)
    }

    //creanado el archivo scene.json
    try {
      // console.log(dataEvento.scenes)
    
      dataEvento.scenes.forEach(async (sceneId, sceneTipo) => { 
        let scene = await Scene.findOne({ _id: sceneId })
        scenes.push(scene)
      })
      await new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000)
      });
        
  fs.writeFile(join(global.__rootdir, `public/${evento}/scene.json`), JSON.stringify(scenes),
        (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
        }
      );
      console.log('El archivo Scene.json ha sido creado')
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error al crear Modelo Scene.json \n${e}`)
    }
    
//crear el archivo objects.json
    let objetos = []
    scenes.forEach(objects => {      
      let obj_local = objects.objects
      obj_local.forEach( async id => { 
        let ob = await Object.findOne({ _id: id })
        objetos.push(ob)
      })
    });
    try {
      await new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000)
      });

      fs.writeFile(join(global.__rootdir, `public/${evento}/objects.json`), JSON.stringify(objetos),
        (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
        }
      );
      console.log('El archivo Objects.json ha sido creado')

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error al crear el Objeto.json  \n ${e}`)
    }

    let elementos = []
    objetos.forEach(elements =>{
        let elem_local = elements.elements
        elem_local.forEach( async id =>{
            let el = await Element.findOne({_id:id})
            elementos.push(el)
        })
    })
    try {
      await new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000)
      });

      fs.writeFile(join(global.__rootdir, `public/${evento}/elementos.json`), JSON.stringify(elementos),
        (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
        }
      );
      console.log('El archivo Elementos.json ha sido creado')

    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error al crear el Elementos.json  \n ${e}`)
    }
    try{
      await new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000)
      });
      ncp(global.__rootdir+`/files`, `public/${evento}`, (err)=>{
        if(err){
          return console.error(err)
        }
        console.log('Carpeta copiada correctamente')
      })
   
    }catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error al copiar directorio  \n ${e}`)
    }
    try{
      await new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000)
      });
     
      var output = fs.createWriteStream(evento+'.zip')
      var archive = archiver('zip')
      //Esuchar para todos los archivos que seran escribidos
      // 'close' el evento close
      output.on('close', function() {
        console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
        console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
      });

      // This event is fired when the data source is drained no matter what was the data source.
      // It is not part of this library but rather from the NodeJS Stream API.
      output.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Data has been drained');
      });

      // good practice to catch warnings (ie stat failures and other non-blocking errors)
      archive.on('warning', function(err) {
        if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
          // log warning
        } else {
          // throw error
          throw err;
        }
      });

      // good practice to catch this error explicitly
      archive.on('error', function(err) {
        throw err;
      });

      // pipe archive data to the file
      archive.pipe(output);
      archive.directory(global.__rootdir+`/public/${evento}/`, false);
      archive.finalize();
      var filepath = global.__rootdir+`/${evento}.zip`
      console.log('El zip ha sido creado')
      
    }catch (e) {
      console.log(`Error al crear el  zip  \n ${e}`)
    }
    // append files from a sub-directory and naming it `new-subdir` within the archive (see docs for more options):
  
    //crear el archivo de Elements.js
 
  }); // fin del foreach :D
```

Comment: **"me exporta los datos y lo comprime en un ZIP pero deseo que me descargue el archivo y lo indique en el browser"**, hmm creo que estas bastante confundido, pues cuando tu descargas algo por media o mediafire, ese dialogo de descarga lo pone automaticamente el navegador, pero eso es si estas **descargando**, valga la redundancia, un archivo a tu computadora, ahora bien, **nodeJS** no tiene acceso directo a ningun archivo o carpeta de tu computadora, si tu estas usando **nodeJS** para intentar descargar archivos en un directorio especifico del usuario entonces dejame decirte que esta mal.

Comment: Recuerda, `nodejs` **corre del lado del servidor**, **javascript** corre del lado del cliente, si quieres que ese mensaje aparezca tienes que hacer que **el cliente** descargue el archivo y no **nodeJS** pues ese mensaje es propio del navegador y no de un lenguaje de programacion en si, tu aparentemente lo que estas haciendo es guardar datos en el backend, y pues el backend nunca te avisara de ello ya que el cliente no tiene porque saber, es mas, el backend (**nodeJS**) nisiquiera interactua de manera directa con el frontend (**javascript**).

Comment: Por ende no es lo mismo descargar un archivo en el **frontend**, que subirlo al **backend**, si tu quieres que aparezca ese mensaje entonces como digo tienes que usar es el **frontend** para descargar el archivo, y no el **backend**.

Comment: O pues... quiza entendi mal la pregunta y enrealidad lo que quieres no es eso, si entendi mal la pregunta entonces me gustaria que pudieras clarificar un poco mas el asunto, de esta manera podremos ayudarte a resolver tu duda.

Comment: ¿Que tal hacer uso de `sendFile()` y establecer las cabeceras adecuadas?. ¿O tal vez redirigir al cliente a una vista que le permita recibir ese archivo que acabas de procesar?